# Add an image to web part header - SP online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, css, customization

I would like to modify the look of my web part so there is an image next to the text - this is an example of a search box I have with how I would like the end result to look -

[image]

I can modify the text easy enough by applying css on the web part zone property but I can't seem to add an image, has anyone ever done this before?

I did think of creating a CEWP above the web part, setting the web part chrome state to 'None' and then I could just build something but that seems a cheap way out, also I have more web parts, I would hate to have to place a CEWP above every one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this for example:

```
/*here I am setting a background image for the webpart title:*/
    .ms-webpart-chrome-title {
      vertical-align: middle;
      position: relative;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      background-image: url(your iamge location);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

You can also use [Font awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icons as well to show icons next to/before title text
example:

```
/*make sure that the font awesome style sheet is loaded first*/
div#WebPartWPQ4_ChromeTitle:before {
  content: '\f098';
  font-family: fontawesome;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, this did the trick. Also appricate the added info - looking at placing font awesome items in so this will help even more

Comment: No worries mate!.

Comment: I cannot get this to work :/